# Show Error message when Entry field is empty?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am working with **Tkinter** for ***GUI*** creation.
I created an Entry field to get some data. Here is the code for that,

```
    self.entry_var = StringVar()
    self.id_label = tk.Label(self.window,
                        text="Enter ID Number: ",
                        font='Helvetica 12 bold')
    self.id_label.place(x=200, y=100)

    self.id_entry = tk.Entry(self.window, textvariable=self.entry_var)
    self.id_entry.insert(0, "Enter ID Number......")
    self.id_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda args: 
    self.id_entry.delete('0', 'end'))
    self.id_entry.place(x=350, y=100)

    self.ip_label = tk.Label(self.window,
                       text="Enter IP Address: ",
                       font='Helvetica 12 bold')
    self.ip_label.place(x=200, y=150)

    self.ip_entry = tk.Entry(self.window, textvariable=self.entry_var)
    self.ip_entry.insert(0, "Enter IP Address......")
    self.ip_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda args: 
    self.ip_entry.delete('0', 'end'))
    self.ip_entry.place(x=350, y=150)
```

And this is the button, when I click this ***add*** button then it gets some data from server.

```
 self.add_button = tk.Button(self.window,
                                text="Add",
                                bg="DodgerBlue2",
                                fg="white",
                                font='Helvetica 12 bold',
                                command=lambda:[self.add_command(), self.check()])
 self.add_button.place(x=350, y=200)
```

My need is, if the entry fields are empty and when click add button I want to show error message like ***"Please fill the required details"***
This is the code for that command,

```
def check(self):
    var = self.entry_var.get()
    if var == '':
        tk.messagebox.showerror("Error!", "Please fill the required details")
```

But it doesn't show error message. It doesn't produce any error. Can anyone findout?

Comment: What is `self.entry_var`? If it is a tkinter `StringVar`, it is not associated with any entry box.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to update that in my question, Now I update that

Comment: In the updated code, `entry_var` is a local variable, but inside `check()` it is an instance variable.  Also you should not associate same variable to different entry boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use different tkinter `StringVar` for different text boxes:

```py
self.id_var = tk.StringVar()
self.ip_var = tk.StringVar()
...
self.id_entry = tk.Entry(self.window, textvariable=self.id_var)
...
self.ip_entry = tk.Entry(self.window, textvariable=self.ip_var)
...
```

Then you can check the values inside these variables inside `check()`:

```py
def check(self):
    id_num = self.id_var.get().strip()
    ip_addr = self.ip_var.get().strip()
    if id_num == "" or ip_addr == "":
        tk.messagebox.showerror("Error!", "Please fill the required details")
```

Comment: Both use StringVar() right, then why we need to use different names

Comment: Different variables reference different instances of `StringVar()`.  I wonder why you think that using same variable works.  What happens when you use same variable for both the entry boxes?

Comment: Yaa your right! I am mistaken. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After few hours I find the mistake what I made. I simply change my button command like this,

```
self.add_button = tk.Button(self.window,
                            text="Add",
                            bg="DodgerBlue2",
                            fg="white",
                            font='Helvetica 12 bold',
                            command=lambda:[self.check(), self.add_command()])
self.add_button.place(x=350, y=200)
```

In my previous command first I put **self.add_command()** and then give **self.check()**. It obviously takes the first command to implement. after I changed this, now the messagebox showed perfectly!